# ssh timeout issue using gcloud compute

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I'm attempting to access my Google Cloud virtual machine via ssh and it is timing out. My attempts have failed through putty as well as through the `gcloud` command line interface.

This is what I can confirm:

- Using `default` network which contains an inbound firewall rule for `0.0.0.0/0` (all sources) on port `tcp:22`
- Private ssh keys are properly setup (tried this manually through puttykeygen as well as through `gcloud` command line with [these](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardssh) instructions), confirmed through Compute Engine -> Metadata -> SSH Keys (also created the keys within the instance itself)
- Established external IP address and attached to VM instance
- Attempted to access through corporate network (where I can connect to AWS instances no problem) as well as through non-corporate network, in other words, there is no proxy issue (or any weird env variables)
- Instance is in zone `europe-west1-b`, I am in Asia so there could be legitimate latency issues but I am able to connect though Cloud Shell

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: Can you access port 22 on that instance's external IP address (visible from `gcloud compute instances list`)?

Comment: I ended up tearing down the instance and rebuilding - which of course worked.

Comment: This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors) might be useful to troubleshoot this kind of issues.

Comment: This [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/953290/google-compute-engine-ssh-connect-to-host-ip-port-22-operation-timed-out) worked for me.